# Applescript date comparison gives unexpected result

Tags: applescript

I have the below Applescript for Outlook 2011 (at bottom). I'm trying to move Inbox messages older than four months to the "on my computer" folder (on my computer of application).

When I run the script, this line always seems to return true, so it archives every message:

```
        if time received of msg > (current date) - 4 * (4 * weeks) then
```

I'm posing this Nov 5, and the oldest messages in my inbox are Sep 1, so this if statement should not trigger.

Here is the Events log of a sample run:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    get every message of inbox
    count every message of inbox
    current date
end tell
tell current application
    current date
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    get time received of item 1 of every message of inbox
    (*time received of item 1 of every message of inbox*)
    move item 1 of every message of inbox to on my computer
    current date
end tell
tell current application
    current date
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    get time received of item 2 of every message of inbox
    (*time received of item 2 of every message of inbox*)
    move item 2 of every message of inbox to on my computer
    current date
end tell
tell current application
    current date
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    get time received of item 3 of every message of inbox
    (*time received of item 3 of every message of inbox*)
    move item 3 of every message of inbox to on my computer
```

Full script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    if messages of inbox = {} then
        error "No messages."
        error -128
    end if
    repeat with msg in messages of inbox
        if time received of msg > (current date) - 4 * (4 * weeks) then
            move msg to on my computer
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 * (4 * weeks) is 4 months ago from Nov 5th, so that's about July 5th. If your time of message is Sept 1 then it surely will trigger it because Sept 1 is greater than July 5. Maybe you meant to use the less than (i.e. <) sign?

Comment: Of course, it was a simple logic error. Thanks for the second set of eyes.